# mdb-angular2 Modal not showing

Tags: angular, material-design

i added mdb-angular2 to my angular app,it working really fine except that i can't seem to get a modal to display on button click, i copied the exact example on the mdn website but its still not working inside my app.
below is my html template code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually forgot about this question, but for those who might face the same problem, here is what i did, I added this to imports on app-module, 
`MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()`

Answer (score 1):

Did you include jQuery in your project? jQuery is required for mdb-angular2 javascript components like modal, carousel, dropdown etc. You can install jQuery via

> npm install --save jquery

After installing jquery you have add the reference to the .angular-cli.json file inside of scripts as follow:

```
{
  ...,
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ],
  ....
}
```

You can also add CDN reference to your index.html file if you don't want to install jQuery and save it as dependency.

`index.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"> 
        </script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```